# How to addforce to mouse location with a player movement script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have two codes that both work fine by themselves but they don't work together. One code moves the player up, down, left, right. The other code rotates the sprite and will launch the sprite facing the direction of the mouse. I can not get both of these codes to work at the same time. Please could use some help.

1st Script is Movement

```
public float moveSpeed;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector2 moveVelocity;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * moveSpeed;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

2nd Script is Launching

```
// Movement
public float thrust = 10f;

public Rigidbody2D rb;

//Aiming
public Camera cam;
Vector2 mousePos;

void Update()
{
    //aiming
    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
    

    //aim
    Vector2 lookDirection = mousePos - rb.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDirection.y, lookDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rb.rotation = angle;
}

void Move()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right * thrust, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just nothing happens or are you getting errors?

Comment: I believe your `MovePosition` is overwriting any sort of force added by `AddRelativeForce`. You will need to change how you are moving your character to have other sort of forces act on it.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I am able to rotate and move around left, right, up, and down. I am just not able to add the force from the launch code. I think I see that MovePosition needs to be changed to maybe rb.velocity. Let me try that and let yall know. Thanks